# the way you tested me?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, relative-clauses

Which one is correct ? Why ? is this adjective clause or noun clause ?

**the way you tested me**

**the way that you tested me**

**the way which you tested me with ?**

Comment: The last two don't sound OK to me. Other options: *how* you tested me, the way *in which* you tested me.

Comment: The first 2 sound OK to me, but the third is incomplete. **the way which you tested me with [something]** where "something" is the method of testing, an exam for example.

Answer (score 1):

> the way you tested me

This is a noun phrase, headed by the noun "way".  There is also a determiner "the" and a relative clause "(that) you tested me".

Because "way" is an implicit object of the verb in the relative clause, the use of "that" is optional.  So (1) and (2) are equivalent and acceptable.

(3) is not idiomatic, The use of "with" is not idiomatic with "way" and "test" (You don't say "test me with this way", you say "test me this way"). It would be possible to use "The exam-paper, which you tested me with."